# Python accept predefined input along with any input inside of a user input and save as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a "terminal" like program written in python and in this program I need to accept "mkdir" and another input and save the input after mkdir as a variable. It would work how sys.argv works when executing a python program but this would have to work from inside the program and I have no idea how to make this work. Also, sorry for the amount of times I said "input" in the title, I wasn't sure how to ask this question.

```
user = 'user'
def cmd1():
    cmd = input(user + '#')
    while True:
        if cmd == 'mkdir ' + sys.argv[1]:   #trying to accept second input here
            print('sys.argv[1]')
            break
        else:
            print('Input not valid')
            break
```

Comment: So if you ran this program with `python terminal.py foo`, you want to check if the user entered `mkdir foo`?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, Im trying to run the program python terminal.py and then they will have a terminal like interface and if they enter "mkdir mydirectory" it will do something with the mydirectory.

Comment: Then why are you comparing the user input to `sys.argv[1]`?  That makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm saying it would behave similar in the way that sys.argv does because in my program you have a terminal where you type commands and it takes the second input as a variable to make a directory. sys.argv takes the input after "python nameofprogram.py" but it does it when you run the program so its similar to what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to accept arguments that are entered after mkdir? If so, you could just split the string with whitespace and get any words after mkdir.

```
cmd = input(user + '#')
cmd_split = cmd.split(' ')

if cmd_split[0] == 'mkdir':
    args = cmd_split[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. By using list compression I converted it to a string and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to *tokenize* your `cmd`. That is, you want to split out the parts of the input by their spaces.

```
cmd = input(user + '#')
parts = cmd.split()

# get the first part as the instruction
instruction = parts[0]

# get everything else as the args
args = parts[1:]
```